# How to save password with Git ssh-agent

Tags: git, ssh-agent

Not sure how or why, but ssh-agent lost all saved passwords.
How can I re-add them?

I would like it if when connecting over SSH to type the password then and have ssh-agent remember it from there on.

I use a config file for different hosts and as far as I remember I didn't have to `ssh-add` for any of the entries there but rather type the password once and then the agent remembered it.

Thank you.

Comment: Git questions are quite welcome here, but since this isn't really Git-specific, I'm voting to move it over to SU where you'll probably get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a shell which didn't get created by the same shell as the one which spawned ssh-agent, then you need to set some env variables so ssh knows which agent to query.

They are displayed when you run ssh-agent for easy import into a new shell.

See http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh for more details.

Comment: So, I added all my keys' passwords to ssh-agent which gets started when Git Bash runs. It remembers them, but once I restart my laptop, it don't know them anymore.

Comment: ssh-agent is not supposed to remember your passphrases across reboots.  If you want ssh keys without passphrases, just create them without passphrases.